# Include entities on a relationship with a custom property in EF Core

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Is there a way to easily include entities from a relationship on a custom property in EF Core in a single query? For example, I have the following structure:

```
public class Report {
    public int TenantId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public List<Document> Documents { get; set; } 
    //...
}

public class Document {
    public int TenantId { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    //... 
}
```

I can't change this structure, i.e. I can't add a property to the Report class to create another relation because Reports are not exclusively related to Documents and I don't want a reference to a Report in a Document.

In my DbContext I declared the relation like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Document>(b => {
    b.HasIndex(e => new { e.TenantId });
});

modelBuilder.Entity<Report>(b => {
    b.HasIndex(e => new { e.TenantId });
    b.HasMany(r => r.Documents).WithOne().HasPrincipalKey("TenantId");
});
```

What I want is to include all Documents in the Report for the specified TenantId. Think of the following database excerpt:

**Documents**

| Id | TenantId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |

**Reports**

| Name | TenantId |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 1 |
| def | 2 |

When fetching all reports I want to have the possibility to include all of the tenant's Documents. For example, fetching the Report `abc` (Tenant 1) should also populate the List in the Report object with Documents 1-3 (because they're all Tenant 1). When fetching the Report `def` it should only populate the List with Document 4.

Unfortunately it doesn't work to just call...

```
reportRepository.GetAll().Where(r => r.Name == 'abc').Include(r => r.Documents)
```

... the list is always empty.

In fact, I could achieve exactly what I'm trying to accomplish with something like this:

```
var report = reportRepository.GetAll().Where(r => r.Name == 'abc').First();
report.Documents = documentRepository.GetAll().Where(d => d.TenantId == report.TenantId).ToList();
```

... but I would really like to have a cleaner solution that doesn't require two queries. This would also make it easier for later reusability because there are more of these structures in the code where I need similar functionality.

Is it possible in EF Core to convert the above two queries into one single query that just includes the Documents that relate on a given property (here TenantId)?

Comment: Can you share `GetByName()` in report manager?

Comment: It's basically a helper function that just calls `reportRepository.GetAll().Where(r => r.Name == 'abc')`, I've updated the question above. The return value of `GetByName()` is of type `IQueryable<Report>`.

Comment: Do you put in the end ```.ToList()```  or you missed it only in the example ?

Comment: You have to relate Documents to Report either by Report's full primary key or by a unique alternate key in Report. It's not clear in your code which of the two options are available. Side note: you can't change this now obviously, but schema per tenant (or even database per tenant) is much easier and safer.

Comment: Correct. No way to do it. There's no relationship between Report and Document. Therefore, it's better not to to pretend there is one in code (if it were possible). Just pull them from the database separately.

Comment: @DarkkL: Where?

Comment: @GertArnold In both tables TenantId is not unique, so that means there is no way to achieve the above?

Comment: I saw your comment coming in my crystal ball and answered it above ;)

Answer (score 0):

try set HasForeignKey and HasPrincipalKey

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Report>(b => {
    b.HasIndex(e => new { e.TenantId });
    b.HasMany(r => r.Documents)
     .WithOne()
     .HasPrincipalKey(d => d.TenantId)
     .HasForeignKey(r => r.TenantId);
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this throws `SQLite Error 19: 'FOREIGN KEY constraint failed'.` Because in both tables TenantId is not unique.